# running command "xcodebuild" exited with error code 65

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build

I have written a project with react-native and it works on Android. Now I want to run it on ios. When I build my project in Xcode it is okay and I have the "Build succeed" message. But when I run the project in my IDE I have the following Error:

```
error Failed to build ios project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening MyProjectName.xcodeproj

** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
myProjectDirectory/ios/build/MyProjectName/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeNavigationTests.xctest/ReactNativeNavigationTests normal x86_64
(1 failure)
....
```

I have tried bellow solutions, but none of them worked for me:

1- I removed the build folder from ios and rebuild the project again.
2- I ran "npm dedupe" 
3- I built a simple new project and I could see "Welcome to React Native..." page on iphone.Then I installed wix v2 library in this project and I could see the page again. It means my problem is not about xcode version or wix installation steps.
4- I have clean and rebuild my project in xcode.

I searched a lot on the internet. But I couldn't find any helpful solution.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your tests are failing.

Try to run tests from Xcode and see if they are ok because my bet is they will fail.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please explain more? I've not worked with Xcode so far.

Comment: See if you can run tests in Xcode with cmd+U. If not, you need to see if you have unit tests target. Keywords to check/google:
- Xcode targets list
- Xcode adding scheme for unit tests
- Xcode running tests